# Copy of PDF then merge breaks output PDF

Tags: php, pdftk, fdf

I am trying to figure out why the following piece of code breaks the outputted PDF.. 
I am copying several PDF files, and they get combined just fine, and the PDF forms get filled out, but when I enable to code below I only get a blank PDF (Nothing filled in) and this shows up on the error log.

```
Warning: input PDF is not an acroform, so its fields were not filled.
```

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $totesi; $i++) {
    $pgnum = ($i + 1);
    if(!copy('../attachment2.pdf', $pgnum . '.pdf')) {
        echo 'Failed to Copy';
     }
     $pdfarr[] .= $pgnum . '.pdf';
}
```

I build the array so I delete only those files afterwards.

This is the command that combines them, maybe I am missing something?

`pdftk *.pdf cat output file.pdf`

And again as said with the code above, it doesn't work.

**Update:**

I tried it with splitting the archive with `pdftk` it works fine for 1 page, if the array contains less than 10 meters, anything more it will error out.

```
if ($totesi >= 1) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $totesi; $i++) {
        if(strpos($type, 'Nodal') !== FALSE) {
            $tempstr .= ' 6';
        } elseif(strpos($type, 'All Inc') !== FALSE) {
            $tempstr .= ' 5';
        }
    }
    shell_exec("pdftk 1.pdf cat ".$pdffile." ". $tempstr ." output 1111111.pdf");
    unlink('1.pdf');
}
```

```
Warning: input PDF is not an acroform, so its fields were not filled.
```

```
pdftk 1.pdf cat 1-4 5 5 output 1111111.pdf
```

This doesn't work either.

Comment: I fixed this by filling out each PDF first in a foreach and merging them afterwards.